# How to help Mac OS X's Finder determine movie dimensions/duration?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, spotlight

In Finder I can see some info about video files: dimensions and duration, but I can see it only for `.mov`, `.mpg`, `.mp4` and maybe some other files. What can I do to see this info for `.mkv`, `.avi`, `.flv`, `.ts` and other video files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finder grabs these details using the built-in Spotlight importer for QuickTime movies (ones that QuickTime will read natively). Unfortunately there are no Spotlight importers available that will read the data for the other video file types you've listed.

Comment: Than I can try to create my own Spotlight Importer :)

Comment: @tig: You sure could!

Comment: Do you think it will be useful for others? I just managed to make it work.

Comment: @tig: I think it would be useful - I'd use it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much time now to finish with all attributes and create package, so, for now, importer just gets video length and dimensions, you can get and try it from my drop box: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3528242/MediaInfoSpotlightImporter.mdimporter.zip

Answer (score 2):

[MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) has a droplet you can install in the Finder.

Comment: I want full integration, not droplet.

Comment: There is a CLI version as well as the Droplet and full GUI application.  You should be able to integrate the CLI version into all kinds of scripts, and perhaps use it with the Spotlight Importer.  http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Download/Mac_OS